# Adjust Mac OS X workflow to recursively scan directory

Tags: automator, workflow

Hi the image below is a screenshot of a workflow i have set up to use Handbrake. The problem is that it only acts on AVI's that are in the root of Movies, it doesn't say, grab an AVI inside Movies->Title->title.avi.

How can i adjust this to do this?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: This might be a better fit on Ask Different?

Answer (score 0):

I use Hazel to trigger Automator workflows.
Recursive application of workflows to embedded folders is easy with Hazel.

In Hazel, add your `top level folder` for monitoring.

## Add the following rule for that folder:

If **all** the following conditions are met

- ***Sub-file/folder Count**  `is greater than`  `0`
- ***Kind is**    `Folder`

Do the following to the matched file or folder:

- ***Run rules on folder contents***

==============

You need another Hazel rule to do the actual work of triggering the Automator workflow.  This can have a wide variety of possible conditions.
The action should be:

***Run Automator workflow***   `name of your workflow`